# R-call multiple variables with same beginning

Tags: r, string

If 9 variables exist that all begin with, say, "hand", I want to be able to pass all of them in a script by shorthand.  Using SAS, I do it as follows:

hand:

Using this, I can run analyses on all variables beginning with "hand" by passing it this way.  My question:  what is the syntax equivalent in R?

Answer (score 3):

There is no base R equivalent short hand

Generally, if you have a data.frame,  you can simply create the appropriate character vector from the  names

```
# if you have a data.frame called df
hands <- grep('^hands', names(df), value = TRUE)
# you can now use this character vector
```

If you are using `dplyr`, it comes with a number of special functions for use within `select`

eg:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(df)
select(df, starts_with("hands"))
```